# SameSite=Lax on JSESSIONID not working with Firefox after redirect

Tags: redirect, firefox, jsessionid, samesite

I try to get the JSESSIONID cookie added to my request after a redirect from a third-party server.

When the user first accesses the App, it returns the **JSESSIONID** with attribute **SameSite=Lax**. Then the user authenticates to the Keycloak server, which **redirects** the user to the App after authentication succeeded.

The problem is that it works with Chromium - that is the JSESSIONID cookie is passed to the App in the redirected request - but it fails with Firefox with the following message in the console : *Cookie “JSESSIONID” with the “SameSite” attribute value “Lax” or “Strict” was omitted because of a cross-site redirect*.

I guess Firefox assumes it's a cross site requests because, though Lax was used and the request is Safe, it is not a Top Level Navigation. But it's weird that Chromium does not treat it as a cross-site request as well.

When I put the App and Keycloak servers in the same domain then it works as it is no longer a cross-site request, but we have other similar use cases with servers we don't have control over their domain, for example online payment server.

Do you know if there is a solution to get this work with all browsers, beside using SameSite=None.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you say "it is not a top-level navigation"? Does it happen in an iframe?

Comment: No IFrame, but the request to the Keycloak server is triggered by the App, so I guessed it was not a Top Level navigation.

I investigated the Firefox source code since then and I think my guess is confirmed by the code from CookieService.cpp. 
The message I got in the console comes from there: [link](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/cookie/CookieService.cpp#1122)

The _blockCookie_ value is set from there: [link](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/cookie/CookieService.cpp#154)
So I think it comes from the **return aIsSafeTopLevelNav**;

Comment: The behavior you observed on Firefox is in accordance with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#lax. For a more detailed answer, please include details about the requests in your question.